# Is there a way to check whether there is any type of file extension included?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am aware of how to check for file extensions, however what I'm asking is if there's a way to check whether the user input was include with any file extension in general.

for example

./myscript index.html is with file extension

Technically I know I could check for file extension using standard bash using something like

```
FILE="$1"
FILE_EXT=${FILE##.*}
```

However issue arrises when i would have a file named `file.script.up.exe` which has multiple dots and obviously it would end my file_ext on `file.script` which is not what I want.

Technically you could use `FILE_EXT=$(echo "$FILE" | awk -F . '{print $NF}')`

but then issue arises when the program would be launched without a file extension

**So basically what I need is to create an if condition to check whether the script was launched with a file extension or not, and depending on the result of that if condition act accordingly**

Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: It is unclear what the issue is. Do you just want to check presence of DOT in filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead :

```
FILE="$1"
FILE_EXT=${FILE##*.}
```

The only change is the asterisk and dot are in reverse order compared to your code.

The `##` expansion operator removes the longest match of the pattern starting from the beginning of the string contained in the variable.  It is a pattern, not a regular expression, so `*` stands for any sequence of characters, and `.` stands for a literal period.  The result is that this expansion removes everything up to and including the last period in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` should use like this in your case: check the number fields before print the last one.

```
FILE_EXT=$(echo "$FILE" | awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If understand right, you want only the last extension in case of multiple dots in the file, e.g. `some.file.ext` you want the `ext`.

This is usually simple, but here are corner cases too. For example the file `.profile` has no extension but has a dot. And like.

So, i would to use the not-so-short solution, maybe someone post you the better one.

```
    line="/some/full/path/name.to.file.ext"

    regex='^(.+)\.([^.]+)$'
    dir=$(dirname "$line")
    base=$(basename "$line")
    ext=""
    if [[ "$base" =~ $regex ]]
    then
            fnoex="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
            ext="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    else
            fnoex="$base"
    fi
    #here you have 4x variables
    # $dir - directory name
    # $base - the filename
    # $fnoex - filename without the extension
    # $ext - the extension
```

The principe is:

- you should first split the `path` to `dirname` and `filename`
- and splitting only the `filename` (exlucing false matches on dots in directory names)

The above should work even for strange path&file names, like

```
/we.i.r d/.file    #no ext
.file.ext.         #no ext
./file.ext..ext2   #ext2
```